# Selecting values from a column with GQL in App Engine

Tags: database, google-app-engine, gql

I want to get the values from a particular column of a table. Whats the correct query for that ?

Eg: Suppose we have a Crisis table which has a "name" column

I want all the values in this column as a list

I tried "SELECT name FROM Crisis" but it didnt work.

Edit:

Here is the exact code:

```
def get(self):
    c = db.GqlQuery('SELECT name FROM Crisis')
```

Error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    c = db.GqlQuery('SELECT name FROM Crisis')
...
BadQueryError: Parse Error: Expected no additional symbols at symbol name

Comment: You are going to need to provide more information.  Paste the exact code you are using.  The docs for this are pretty good, http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview.html

Comment: Ok I pasted the code and error. Will check the docs too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't select a single column from an entity.  This is one of the most basic limitations of the App Engine datastore.  You can retrieve the entire entity, or only its key.

```
def get(self):
  c = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Crisis')

  for entity in c:
    logging.info(entity.name)
```

Edit:
To be more precise, there are no "columns" in App Engine.

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful. One more thing: what exactly is logging.info() ?

Comment: It's the module that you use to print out stuff to the App Engine logs. http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html

Comment: I don't think this is still the case. The GQL Reference (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference) describes "SELECT <property list>" and I'm seeing it working in the Datastore Viewer on the AppEngine dashboard now...